# Select records from a particular date

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my table I store the data like `2015-11-24 14:53`.

When I try to select the records from the date `2015-11-24`

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS where id='22' 
and date >= date('2015-11-24 00:00')  
and date <= date('2015-11-24 23:59')
```

I don't get anything.. (there are records with that date)

Comment: You are selecting a record with id 22, you will only get that one if its date is between the 2 given values.

Comment: So I'm assuming your date is stored as [`TEXT`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're selecting by `id`, which should be unique, there is no need to select by `date`. You can think of selecting by non-unique fields (in this case, `date`) like searching. But you're saying "SELECT this specific row (the row with id 22) AND then check if it meets these date parameters". So using this statement you'll only ever get 0 or 1 results.

You should change your statement to something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS where 
date >= date('2015-11-24 00:00')  
and date <= date('2015-11-24 23:59')
```

However, as Allinone51 pointed out, if your field is of type [`TEXT`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), the safe bet is to call the [`date()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function on your text field

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS where 
date(date) >= date('2015-11-24 00:00')  
and date(date) <= date('2015-11-24 23:59')
```

That being said, the non-date comparison should work. To test this, open sqlite3 in your command window and run `select date('2015-11-24 23:59');`. The result will be `2015-11-24`.

If we test this with a date from the previous day, here are the results using various combinations of boolean operators and use of the `date()` function.

```
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') == '2015-11-24');
1
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') >= '2015-11-23');
1
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') <= '2015-11-23');
0
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') < '2015-11-23');
0
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') > '2015-11-23');
1
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') == date('2015-11-24'));
1
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') >= date('2015-11-23'));
1
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') <= date('2015-11-23'));
0
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') < date('2015-11-23'));
0
sqlite> SELECT (date('2015-11-24 23:59') > date('2015-11-23'));
1
```

So if I put in sample `date` values in your statement, I end up with this result

```
SELECT date('2015-11-24') >= date('2015-11-24 00:00') 
and date('2015-11-24') <= date('2015-11-24 23:59');
1
```

One final note: As Allinone51 pointed out in the comments, `date('2015-11-24 00:00')` and `date('2015-11-24 23:59')` return the same value, `2015-11-24`.

```
sqlite> SELECT date('2015-11-24 00:00');
2015-11-24
sqlite> SELECT date('2015-11-24 23:59');
2015-11-24
```

Based on that, perhaps you wanted the [`datetime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function?

Comment: I may be wrong but, date('2015-11-24 00:00') isn't it returning the same value as ('2015-11-24 23:59')?

Comment: @Allinone51 yes it is, but that was what OP used in his original question, so I decided to use it. Without having their data, I try to keep the examples as close as possible to what they've presented.

Answer (score 3):

You can select all the records with a certain date like this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE date('yourDateColumn') = 'your date';
```

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE date(date) = '2015-11-24';
```

date() selects the 'date' part of your DATETIME. For example:

```
date('2014-01-01 00:00:00') would return '2014-01-01'
```